# Probability of a random CNF being satisfiable

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, satisfiability

Suppose we pick a 3-CNF with $n$ variables and $k$ clauses uniformly at random. How much is known about the probability $p(n,k)$ of being satisfiable?

Comment: This is, I think, a known thing. I recall hearing that for $3-CNF$, one needed only that the number of clauses $k$ be less than $\approx 40 n$, and then almost all such CNF were satisfiable. After which point almost all instances were unsatisfiable. Can't find a reference though.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that there is a threshold $r_c$ such that, for sequences $n_j, k_j \to \infty$ with $k_j/n_j  \to r$, if $r > r_c$ then $p(n,k) \to 0$ while if $r < r_c$ then $p(n,k) \to 1$.  Experimentally $r_c \approx 4.27$, but AFAIK a closed form for $r_c$ is not known.  There are some rigorous upper and lower bounds; I don't know what the current best bounds are.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if this distribution is related to the Ramsey one: the number of monochromatic $r$-cliques in a random coloring of $K_n$ has a similar phase shift...